# Running android java's native libraries under linux

Tags: java, android, c++, linux, android-native-library

I have well-working simple android app(graphically does nothing, but calculates some data), that uses native libraries, those libraries is for x86, so I am hoping to make that code work under x86 ubuntu as a simple compiled java binary.
So after finding all library dependencies compiler tells me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
lib/libgnustl_shared.so: lib/libgnustl_shared.so: undefined symbol: __sF
```

After a bit googling I found that **__sF** is some kind of android specified parameters array, that accesible in the android env(or elsewhere, I actually don't know).
**libgnustl_shared.so** depends from **libm.so** and **libdl.so**, that comes with ubuntu.

Should I try to find android x86 **libm.so** and **libdl.so**? Or try to implement some how **__sF** in java code?

(main point is to solve issue with **libgnustl_shared.so**, other libraries is written manually by my co-worker so I dont expect any harm from them)

I hope someone has the sacred knowledge to help me make it work. Appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm sure that its possible. Does really nobody knows?

Comment: Hi. Any news on how to fix this problem?

Comment: @SergeyUnk I gave up on it at the time..